# accessing yahoo web services throws an UnknownHostException

Tags: java

I am trying to  parse  Yahoo! Web Service XML result with XPath.

the code i am using  is

```
    String request = "http://api.search.yahoo.com/WebSearchService/V1/webSearch?appid=YahooDemo&query=umbrella&results=10";
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    GetMethod method = new GetMethod(request);        
    // Send GET request
    int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);        
    if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        System.err.println("Method failed: " + method.getStatusLine());
    }
    InputStream rstream = null;        
    // Get the response body
    rstream = method.getResponseBodyAsStream();     
    // Process response
    Document response = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(rstream);        
    XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xPath=factory.newXPath();        
    //Get all search Result nodes
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList)xPath.evaluate("/ResultSet/Result", response, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    int nodeCount = nodes.getLength();
```

i am getting exception like this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: api.search.yahoo.com
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at                            org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultPro   tocolSocketFactory.java:80)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:122)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at org.tcs.com.newsfeed.YahooWebServiceParseResults.main(YahooWebServiceParseResults.java:38)
```

Comment: Not sure why your code can't reach that host, but you should follow the URL yourself. There's a message saying WebSearchService is shut down.

Comment: Try to ping the host in the same machine. Does it work? Maybe DNS failure / HOST file configuration failure. @ChrisHayes good try!

Comment: Yahoo Web Search Service was shut down in 2010 . How come OP is still trying to develop something on it ? Migrate to YQL . See: http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/important-api-updates-changes-8060.html

Comment: Check if you are behind firewall/proxy. If thats the case then go for proxy configuration for `HttpClient`.

Answer (score -1):

This exception indicates that the java client can't resolve the DNS name api.search.yahoo.com.

From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/UnknownHostException.html): "Thrown to indicate that the IP address of a host could not be determined."

For whatever reason, your program can't resolve the DNS name. What happens when you try to ping this host name from the command line?

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @ChrisHayes: Not only is it an answer, it's pretty much the *only* answer. The exception clearly indicates that DNS resolution isn't working.

Comment: I am able to ping the host from my machine. I am able to hit that url in eclipse browser also. I am not able connect any host through may java httpclient

Comment: If you have to end your answer with a question to the OP, then it's not an answer. If it were something like "Depending on what happens when you try to ping the host from the command line, the cause could be X, Y, or Z", that would be an appropriate answer.

Comment: On a separate note, the web service isn't available, but the hostname still resolves. This isn't the source of the error.

Comment: @ChrisHayes: FYI — The question at the end is a socratic question: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socratic_question. It exactly diagnoses the cause as much as the information available from the original stack trace allows, and suggests an appropriate follow-up investigation. There are approximately 13 million </sarcasm> possible causes for a broken DNS lookup, and listing them all is not necessarily going to be helpful for someone else asking this question in the future. "This exception means DNS didn't work" is a helpful answer.

Comment: OTOH, the fact that the REST api is no longer available is a relevant comment, as it's a human problem not related to the programming question "what does this UnknownHostException mean?".

Comment: @ChrisHayes thanks, i know that web service isn't available. by browsing through net i came to know that it is because of proxy. but i didn't understand from browser i am able to hit why not through java program. do i need any configuration changes for make this work